# How to get a combobox2 to display records only relating to the selection made in combobox1?

Tags: ms-access

SO I am making a database for a company and i have a form that's been split in half the top half has customer information and a Combobox1 for selection. the bottom half is for project bid information and is set up to display one record at a time not every record available for that customer. I want to put a combobox2 on the project half to select project records related to only the customer selected in combobox1. The problem I'm having is combobox2 has every record listed from the project table instead of those only related to the customer selected in combobox1 and it doesn't change to the project information it just stays on the same one no matter what I select.

P.S the customer half of the form works perfectly as I intended it to.

Comment: There's a few ways to do this.   I like to trigger it on the AfterUpdate of Combo1, and change the RowSource of Combo2 to include a WHERE statement referencing the Combo1 value.

Answer (score 0):

This is called cascading or dependent comboboxes - a common topic. Search Stackoverflow or Google. If you want combobox used to select filter criteria, it must be UNBOUND. It would probably be better placed in the top half. By 'split' do you mean a form/subform arrangement? If a subform then its LinkMasterFields property could propably reference the combobox while the LinkChildFields property references key field in the subform recordset.

Otherwise, code needed to filter or move to desired project record based on selection.

Comment: It's not a subform I just added the fields and used a line to to cut the form in half so it wouldnt display in a datasheet. Its supposed to be a bid form that they can print and have the customer sign.

Comment: Forms are intended for screen display and reports for printing. Each can be made to act somewhat like the other but not always nicely. To print a form it will have to be filtered to the one record desired. It would be best to display a form to user but print a report filtered by the ID selected in combobox.